# how to rearrange a dictionary in python

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, dictionary

```
dictionary = {(1,1):[(2,2),[(3,3),(4,4)],5]}

dictionary[(2,2)] = [(3,3),[(4,4),(5,5)],6]

dictionary[(3,3)] = [(4,4),[(5,5),(6,6)],7]

print dictionary
```

Above code gives output as:

```
{(3, 3): [(4, 4), [(5, 5), (6, 6)], 7], (1, 1): [(2, 2), [(3, 3), (4, 4)], 5], (2, 2): [(3, 3), [(4, 4), (5, 5)], 6]}
```

But, I wanted the output in order as input provided i.e,

```
{(1,1):[(2,2),[(3,3),(4,4)],5],(2,2):[(3,3),[(4,4),(5,5)],6],(3,3):[(4,4),[(5,5),(6,6)],7]}
```

How can  I rearrange the dictionary?

Comment: Instead of trying to do this, take a look at ordered dictionaries https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: do you need it ordered in general or just when printed?

Comment: ordered when it prints..

Answer (score 3):

You should use *OrderedDict* from https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

A normal python Dictonary is not ordered at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ordered dictionary instead of normal dictionary like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_dict = OrderedDict()

my_dict[(1,1)] = [(2,2), [(3,3), (4,4)], 5]
my_dict[(2,2)] = [(3,3), [(4,4), (5,5)], 6]
my_dict[(3,3)] = [(4,4), [(5,5), (6,6)], 7]

print(my_dict)
# Output: OrderedDict([((1, 1), [(2, 2), [(3, 3), (4, 4)], 5]), ((2, 2), [(3, 3), [(4, 4), (5, 5)], 6]), ((3, 3), [(4, 4), [(5, 5), (6, 6)], 7])])

print(my_dict[(1, 1)])
# Output: [(2, 2), [(3, 3), (4, 4)], 5]
```